# How can I use urllib.request in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module

When I try to use this code in Python 2.7.4:

```
import urllib.request

class App():
    def main(self):
        inp = raw_input('Please enter a string\n')
        print(inp)
        inp = input('Please enter a value\n')
        print(inp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().main()
```

I get an error that says 'no import named request'.
If I instead write `import urllib`, then I don't get any import error, but I can't use the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`urllib.request` is for Python 3. For Python 2, you'll want to do:

```
from urllib import urlopen
```

Or use the [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) module:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
```

You shouldn't be getting an `IndentationError`, but you may have done some minor error.

Comment: @eddard.stark Could you please edit your question and show me the exact code when you get an `IndentationError`?

Comment: @eddard.stark Yes, the `pass` keyword is indented too much.

Comment: `App().main()` is also indented one too much.

Comment: @Haidro, I am not getting any indentation error for the first code. I am getting import error for that code. And I have checked and double checked the the second code. There is no indentation error there. Ideone is just showing it wrong.

Comment: Guys, I am not getting any indentation error for the first code. I am getting import error for that code.

Comment: @eddard.stark Your code does not reproduce any of those errors. Did you happen to name your file `urllib` or possible name your directory `urllib`?

Comment: I just downloaded your paste from ideone, and it appears you are using a mixture of tabs and spaces.  You need to be consistent

Comment: @Haidro, the name of the file is urllib.py

Comment: @Haidro, is that a problem?

Comment: @eddard.stark Yes, it is trying to import from your file. Rename the file, so it imports from the built in module instead.

Comment: @eddard.stark Sorry for not responding earlier

Comment: thanks a lot @Haidro. Thanks for sticking with my problem. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple sandbox implementation for python2.7:

```
import urllib

def main():
    #one indentation level
    print urllib.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com").read ()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

If this code runs and yours doesn't, then the problem is not with importing/using urllib. It runs on my machine using pthon2.7.4.

Alternative version:

```
from urllib import urlopen

def main():
    #one indentation level
    print urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com").read ()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Or using your [App-Class](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html):

```
import urllib

class App:
    def main(self):
        print urllib.urlopen("http://stackoverflow.com").read ()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App().main()
```

Comment: the name of the file is urllib.py. is that a problem?

Comment: why and what should i name it?

Comment: Basically you are trying to import yourself. Name it anything but the name of another module you want to import, for example `rhabarberkuchen.py`.

Comment: Glad to help. One junior programmer of mine fell into exactely the same trap and it took us quite a time to spot the error, as nobody expected him to name his file like the module he used.